# How to run httpUser class methods as sequentially using Sequential task class

Tags: performance-testing, locust

I have created https user class with get/put methods but i want to run those method in sequentially...Can i use Sequential Task class? How to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from locust import User, task, between, SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, LoadTestShape

class JsonHolderImpl(HttpUser):
    """
    HttpUser class where we can have get, post methods
    """
    
    abstract = True
    host = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_user(self):
        response = self.client.get("/posts/1")
        print(response, response.text, response.status_code)



class JsonHolderTests(SequentialTaskSet):
     """
     A sequential task set class to execute methods in sequence
     """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.get = JsonHolderImpl(environment = self.user.environment)

    @task
    def sample(self):
        self.get.get_user()

    @task
    def sample2(self):
        self.get.get_user()


class JsonHolderRunner(User):

    """
    A runner class which executes sequential task sets
    """
    wait_time = between(10, 15)
    tasks = [JsonHolderTests]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).